# Syntax error in switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

My problem is the following: I have a switch-statement where I need to check if a string is equal to a specific symbol, however, with this code:

```
[...]
switch($str) { 
    [...]
    case (: $output .= $example_array[rand(0,3)] . '|'; break;

    case ): $output .= $example_array[rand(4,8)] . '|'; break;
    [...]
}
[...]
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE) in [...]

Do I need to change to `if` `else` statement or can I work around this somehow?

Comment: what the heck are those parens doing where values should be (right after the word case both times)?

Comment: Are you trying to use open and close parens as the string to test against? I think it's the `case (:` part that's blowing up. If you need to test for case = (, you need to enclose the paren in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at the syntax of [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

You need quotes around the character you want to match.

```
case "(":
  $output .= $example_array[rand(0,3)] . '|';
  break;
```

Comment: Yup. Worked great. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're evaluating a string ( or ) so use quotes:

```
case ')':

case '(':
```